# Where in the ECMAScript spec for the Date() constructor does the time value get converted to epoch time?

Tags: javascript, datetime

I understand that an ECMAScript date just stores a time value in epoch time (the number of milliseconds since midnight on 1 January 1970 UTC).

But looking over the [algorithm for the `Date()` constructor](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-date), I only see where the argument values are converted to milliseconds; I don't see where the millisecond value is converted to epoch time. Where does that step happen?

Comment: I don't understand: if the milliseconds are not the epoch time already, what do you imagine they represent then?

Comment: "*l. Let dv be TimeClip(UTC(finalDate)).*"

Comment: @trincot, at some point in the construction of `Date`, an offset from the 1970 epoch must be subtracted from the input, otherwise I guess we'd end up with ms since 1 A.D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Date` constructor algorithm](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-date) calls [*MakeDay*](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-makeday), which returns the number of days since epoch for the argument values. [*MakeDate*](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-makedate) then does convert that number of days to the number milliseconds by simple multiplication.
*MakeDay* contains the following step:

> 8. Find a finite [time value](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-time-values-and-time-range) `t` such that [*YearFromTime*](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#eqn-YearFromTime)(`t`) is `ym` and [*MonthFromTime*](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#eqn-MonthFromTime)(`t`) is `mn` and [DateFromTime](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-date-number)(`t`) is 1;

This is a rather obscure definition, using the operations defined in [21.4.1.3 "*Year Number*"](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-year-number). There we can find the formula

> DayFromYear(y) = (365 × (ℝ(y) - 1970) + floor((ℝ(y) - 1969) / 4) - floor((ℝ(y) - 1901) / 100) + floor((ℝ(y) - 1601) / 400))

This comes out to have "day 0" as the first day of 1970.

But rather than deriving that from this formula, we can just read [21.4.1.1 "*Time Values and Time Range*"](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-time-values-and-time-range):

> The exact moment of midnight at the beginning of 1 January 1970 UTC is represented by the time value `+0`.

Comment: I think it's simpler than that. [Step 5(k)](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-date) creates a local time value from local date values: "*Let finalDate be MakeDate(MakeDay(yr, m, dt), MakeTime(h, min, s, milli)).*". It returns a number that is the local offset in milliseconds from the epoch. AIUI, that's where the OP is up to. Then 5(l) converts it to UTC: "*Let dv be TimeClip(UTC(finalDate)).*". That final time value is used for the returned Date object.

Comment: @RobG Yes, `MakeDate` returns the number of milliseconds since epoch, but I understood the OP's question to be where in that algorithm the epoch is specified.

Comment: @RobG But you're right, I kinda skipped over this days-to-milliseconds conversion in my first paragraph. Edited.

Comment: Thanks @Bergi, this is what I was getting at - where the offset from 1970 gets factored in.